# functions in class data members

Tags: php, function, data-members

In PHP (v 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11) I'm not allowed to initialize data members with functions or arrays of functions. These two violate the PHP syntax on a basis of `syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), expecting ')'`:

```php
class Foo {
  var $a = array(
    function() {}
  );
}
```

and:

```php
class Foo {
  var $a = function() {};
}
```

Nevertheless, this is allowed:

```php
$a = array(function() {});
```

Why can't I assign functions to data members in classes?

For ease of reproduceability:

```php
echo '<?php class Foo { var $a = array(function() {}); } ?>' | php
echo '<?php class Foo { var $a = function() {}; } ?>' | php
echo '<?php $a = array(function() {}); ?>' | php
```

Comment: @rizier123 : even though the answer might be the same, the question differs significantly.

Comment: *even though the answer might be the same* Exactly, the answer is the same.

Comment: The answer is indeed adequate. Nevertheless, the suggested question was not specifically asked for assigning functions. It requires me (OP) to know that there is a difference between initializing a class variable like `var $a = 5;` and `var $a = function() {};`, which I didn't.

Comment: (In any case, thank you for the quick answer)